# Layout of bar plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, positioning, bar-chart

I have the following bar plot:
[image]

I want to change the following in the bar plot:

- '1' and '2' on the axis group together, i.e. closer together and is called group A1. The group name 'A1' should be listed above the bar plot. The same holds for 'A2'
- Between '1' and '2' (and '3' and '4') the space should be smaller, but the space between group 'A1' and 'A2' must be larger, such that it is visible we are talking about two different groups. Colors may be in black.
- I want to draw a horizontal line.

This is what I want:
[image]

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        scaled y ticks = false, 
        scaled x ticks = false, 
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}
    }
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend entries={First,Second, Total},
legend to name=legendLF,
legend columns = 3,
height=50mm,
width= 15cm,
     x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel={Value},
        xlabel= {Position},
                xtick={1,2,3,4},
                    enlargelimits=0.1,
       legend style={
          at={(0.75,-0.2)},
          anchor=north,
        },
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=10pt
      ]
     \addplot[gray!20!gray,fill=gray!60!gray]
        coordinates {(01,46) (02,51)
          (03,51) (04,58) };
        \addplot[darkgray!20!darkgray,fill=darkgray!80!darkgray]
        coordinates {(01,47) (02,53)
          (03,56) (04,72)};
      \addplot[black!20!black,fill=black!80!black]
        coordinates {(01,60) (02,56)
          (03,58) (04,69) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{legendLF}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `legend to name` enables a legend export mode instead of drawing the legend, in this case you can't control the position of legend with `legend style={at={(0.5,-0.4)}}`.

Place nodes with

```
\node[red] at (rel axis cs:0.18,0.7) {$A_1$}; 
\node[red] at (rel axis cs:0.78,0.7) {$A_2$};
```

Draw red line with

```
\draw[red,thick](yticklabel* cs:0.53)--({yticklabel* cs:0.53} -|{xticklabel* cs:1});
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        scaled y ticks = false, 
        scaled x ticks = false, 
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}
    }
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend entries={First,Second, Total},
%legend to name=legendLF,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.4)},anchor=north,legend columns = 3},
height=50mm,
width= 15cm,
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel={Value},
xlabel= {Position},
symbolic x coords={1,2, ,3,4},
xtick=data,
enlargelimits=0.1,
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
ybar=0pt,
bar width=10pt]

     \addplot[gray!20!gray,fill=gray!60!gray]
        coordinates {(1,46) (2,51) (3,51) (4,58)};
     \addplot[darkgray!20!darkgray,fill=darkgray!80!darkgray]
        coordinates {(1,47) (2,53) (3,56) (4,72)};
     \addplot[black!20!black,fill=black!80!black]
        coordinates {(1,60) (2,56) (3,58) (4,69)};

     \node[red] at (rel axis cs:0.18,0.7) {$A_1$}; 
     \node[red] at (rel axis cs:0.78,0.7) {$A_2$};
     \draw[red,thick](yticklabel* cs:0.53)--({yticklabel* cs:0.53} -|{xticklabel* cs:1});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\ref{legendLF}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]